# How to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription, NSCameraUsageDescription, and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription to info.plist for react-native-image-picker

Tags: react-native

I'm new to xcode and react-native. I'm trying to use react-native-image-picker to add a user profile (uploaded to s3). react-native-image-picker's getting started assumes you have knowledge of info.plist. I'm not 100% sure how to proceed given:

> For iOS 10+, Add the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription,
>   NSCameraUsageDescription, and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription (if
>   allowing video) keys to your Info.plist with strings describing why
>   your app needs these permissions

I know the info.plists are found in the ios folder, but

- which info.plist do these permissions need to get added to (there's multiple inside ios folder: build, RNapp, RNapp-tvOS, RNapp.xcodeproj, etc)?
- how does the XML look?
- Should this be happening in xcode instead of my text editor?

[docs](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker)

Answer (score 5):

if you don't providing the privacy key in  Info.plist, then your app is crash. You can see its log why crashed.

You will find these code below in the info.plist of your xcode , open in text editor.
adding these will grant the permission for using camera, PhotoLibrary, Video

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Camera Usage</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} PhotoLibrary Usage</string>

<key>NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Video Subscribe Usage</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

add ti info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit the plist that you need the permissions for. If you are making a mobile app that would be: RNapp.

You could do this in a text editor but the easiest way to do it is in Xcode.

Open the plist, on the last item (making sure it is not expanded_ hit the `+` button to create a new row to provide a key to define a value for. Xcode should autocomplete on the keys you provided above and set the value to the appropriate type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes in this example RNapp is the project name. So put it in the info.plist from that folder? What does the XML look like? I guess I need more details preferably.